# Is Strict Mode isolated to individual JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, strict

When including `'use strict';` at the beginning of a JavaScript file which is included in an HTML page, would any subsequent included files or JS adhere to the Strict Mode ruling established in the first file? Or would Strict Mode be isolated to the first file?

Example:

```
<script src="/path/to/file_using_use_strict.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/file_omitting_use_strict.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log('Hello! Am I strict?');
</script>
```

I checked the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), but couldn't find an example outlining this specific situation. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just test this and see?

Comment: Consider concatenating a strict mode script with a non-strict mode script: the entire concatenation looks strict! The inverse is also true: non-strict plus strict looks non-strict. Concatenation of strict mode scripts with each other is fine, and concatenation of non-strict mode scripts is fine. Only concatenating strict and non-strict scripts is problematic. It is thus recommended that you enable strict mode on a function-by-function basis (at least during the transition period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Strict mode MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode):

> Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to individual functions.

So the answer to your question is yes, strict mode only applies to the scripts or functions where you invoke it.